How state management of Spark Structured Streaming queries work when using RocksDB
I'm running a Spark Structured Streaming application that reads from a Kinesis stream, applies some  non-stateful transformations and then performs a dropDuplicates operation using an id, but with no watermark. The state is being stored on RocksDB (Spark 3.5.1)
This is what I'm trying to understand:

Where is the state related data stored? Memory, Disk or on my checkpoint location? Looking at the memoryUsedBytes metric, I see that the memory used to track state keeps growing and then at some point it goes down.



When checking for duplicates, considering that not all keys are stored in memory, does RocksDB have to access a store that does not provide low latency? So far I haven't had major issues with latency, could that happen if state gets too big?
When restarting the streaming query, how does it recover previous state? If state is retrieved from my checkpoint location, does it mean that if it keeps getting bigger, recovery will start to become slower?

I tried looking for some more detailed articles about how RocksDB is used in Spark Streaming, but couldn't find one

Where are you getting that graph from? Is it based on the metrics from the StreamingQueryProgress?

@NeilRamaswamy yes, it's coming from the StreamingQueryProgress
